# Clean recv at paramiko channel

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to establish SSH session, run first block of command, then run second block of command, but i need to capture output only from the second block.
How can I clean recv buffer in paramiko in more clean and right way ?
Now I re-establish SSH session, but it is ugly and stupid in my opinion

```
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect('10.10.10.50', username='admin', password='admin')
x=client.invoke_shell()
x.send('en')
x.send('\n')
x.send('conf t')
x.send('\n')
x.send('hostname 11')
x.send('\n')
x.send('exit')
x.send('\n')
x.close()
time.sleep(1)
client.connect('10.10.10.50', username='admin', password='admin')
x=client.invoke_shell()
x.send('sh users\n')
time.sleep(1)
output=x.recv(65535)
print output
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `recv()`ing all available data from the channel before `send()`ing *the second block*?

Comment: yes, it workes
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to clear buffer before "x.send('sh users\n')"

```
while not x.recv_ready():
    time.sleep(10)
output = x.recv(65535).decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in comments:

> what about recv()ing all available data from the channel before send()ing the second block? – whjm
>
> yes, it workes thanks ! – pnd